# MultiByteToWideChar does not convert my string well

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I'm building a synthetic UTF-8 string on `std::string` and try to convert it with `MultiByteToWideChar`.
Here is my code:

```
std::string str;
str += 'A'; 
str += char(0);
str += 'B';
str += char(0);
str += 'C';
str += char(0);
str += char(0);
str += char(0);
std::wstring wstr;

if (str.empty()){
    wstr = L"";
}
int sizeNeeded = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.data(), str.size(), NULL, 0) + 1;
std::wstring wstrTo(sizeNeeded, 0);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.data(), str.size(), &wstrTo[0], sizeNeeded);
wstr = wstrTo;

std::wcout << wstr;
```

It turns out that `MultiByteToWideChar` is not turning `str` to simply L"ABC" string, but turns every character separetly to `wchar_t` - meaning that the pair `'A' + char(0)` does not turn to `L'A'` but to `L'A' + L'\0'`

Am I doing something wrong here or is this the expected behaviour of `MultiByteToWideChar` ?

Comment: winapi is defenitly a C api.

Comment: @DavidHaim Yup, but `std::(w)string` and `std::wcout` don't have much to do with C.

Comment: Why would you store NUL bytes in a UTF-8 string? And why would you expect them to vanish?

Comment: @DavidHaim but the usage does not have to do much with `C`, IMHO.

Comment: UTF-8 encoded strings should not contain any zero bytes, and you should not attempt to manually terminate a `std::string` object (what I guess the double-zero you add at the end is doing. What you're doing when adding characters to `str` like you do in the code shown, is manual UTF-16 encoding of the characters.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the difference between 'A' and L'A' is that extra byte that when the character is Unicode but also exist on ascii , the extra byte is always 0

Comment: Dead wrong, David. You are confusing Unicode with UTF-16 or UCS-2! Now, the reason that in those encodings you find null bytes is that their basic unit consists of two bytes and for codepoints < 256 the MSB is null. These null bytes don't have a representation equivalent in UTF-8 though.

Comment: "Multibyte" doesn't mean that it takes 2 chars to make it one wide.  It's not up to you to pad with 0.  "Multibyte" just means that some chars (in fact those beyond ascii) may have a special encoding saying that several successive chars have to be combined into a single wider value.

Comment: see the comment I put below. If so, I don't get the whole char/wchar_t converstion. I thought that wchar_t is double in size then char , in order to accept values beyond 128. if the unicode character exist also in ascii - then the first byte has the ascii value, and the second is just 0.

Comment: That's UTF-16. But you are trying to encode UTF-8.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::string str;
str += 'A'; 
str += char(0);
str += 'B';
str += char(0);
str += 'C';
str += char(0);
str += char(0);
str += char(0);
```

This is NOT producing a UTF-8 encoded string!  It is producing a UTF-16 encoded string.

```
int sizeNeeded = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.data(), str.size(), NULL, 0) + 1;
```

You are telling `MultiByteToWideChar()` to interpret the raw bytes of `str` as UTF-8, even though it is not actually encoded in UTF-8.

Unicode codepoint `U+0000` is valid in UTF-8 (it is encoded as `0x00`), so every `0x00` character in `str` is going to be interpreted as codepoint `U+0000`, and the rest of the characters will be interpreted as-is since they are all less than `U+0080`.  Thus, there are no *multi-byte* sequences in your "UTF-8" string, only *single-byte* sequences.

You end up with a UTF-16 `wstring` containing the following codepoints:

```
0x41 -> U+0041 
0x00 -> U+0000
0x42 -> U+0042
0x00 -> U+0000
0x43 -> U+0043
0x00 -> U+0000
0x00 -> U+0000
0x00 -> U+0000
```

Had you encoded `str` as UTF-8 properly, and then interpret it as UTF-8, you would have ended up with a correct UTF-16 `wstring`:

```
std::string str;
str += 'A'; 
str += 'B';
str += 'C';
str += char(0);
```

```
0x41 -> U+0041 
0x42 -> U+0042
0x43 -> U+0043
0x00 -> U+0000
```

Or, if you leave `str` encoded as UTF-16 and interpret it as UTF-16 (which you cannot do with `MultiByteToWideChar()`, you would have to do it manually), you would still end up with a UTF-16 `wstring` containing the correct codepoints:

```
std::string str;
str += 'A'; 
str += char(0);
str += 'B';
str += char(0);
str += 'C';
str += char(0);
str += char(0);
str += char(0);
```

```
0x41 0x00 -> U+0041 
0x42 0x00 -> U+0042
0x43 0x00 -> U+0043
0x00 0x00 -> U+0000
```

Answer (score 3):

You are encoding the string `"ABC"` incorrectly. The null characters are spurious. Characters in the ASCII range are encoded in a single octet in UTF-8.

Encode it like this:

```
std::string str;
str += 'A'; 
str += 'B':
str += 'C';
str += 0;
```

Although

```
std::string str = "ABC";
```

is simpler.

Comment: the point is that if I delete the whoele multibyte process and do something like `wstr = (wchar_t*)str.data();` the str get encoded correctly, how do explain it?

Comment: Because you encoded a UTF-16 string. The code in my answer encodes a UTF-8 string. Which is what you said you wanted to do.

Comment: so wchar_t in windows is a utf-16 charater?

Comment: so MutliByteTo... has any more specialty other than turn char array to wchar_t array? we could just write in C++ wstr(str.begin(),str.end()) and gain the same functionality..

Comment: @DavidHaim: No, that is not what `wstr(str.begin(), str.end())` actually does. And yes, `MultiByteToWideChar()` actually does something. You are just not using it correctly.

Comment: @David You probably need to make sure you understand how these encodings work before going on

Comment: that does not answer my question :)

Comment: You asked about your code and why MBTWC did not behave as you expected

Comment: I meant, the question in the comment. let's say I have std::string and I want to convert it to std::wstring. I can use the C++ iterators way wstr(str.begin(), str.end()) and also MultiByteToWideChar functions. are there any extra functionality to MultiByteToWideChar over the standard C++ way?

Comment: @DavidHaim: Yes, there is a difference. Using `wstr(str.begin(), str.end())` simply copies the elements of `str` **as-is** into `wstr`, extending them from `char` to `wchar_t`.  That is all it does.  Which is perfectly fine **ONLY FOR ASCII CHARACTERS 0-127**.  That will NOT WORK for non-ASCII characters.  `MultiByteToWideChar()`, on the other hand, performs an actual conversion from the specified codepage (UTF-8) to UTF-16, and will handle all Unicode characters correctly (if they are encoded correctly to begin with, which your example is not).

Comment: Well, they don't do the same thing. Your iterator will convert using CP_ACP. You passed CP_UTF8.

Comment: @DavidHaim: You REALLY need to read up on what UTF-8 and UTF-16 actually are, how Unicode codepoints are encoded in each of them, and how codepoints can be converted between them (a conversion from one UTF to other UTF is loss-less).

Comment: @Remy Is that it? Not even ANSI -> UTF-16

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the iterator copy will not do any conversion at all, not even a CP_ACP conversion.  It is a straight 1-to-1 copy of each value in the iteration.

Comment: @David OK, I'm sure Remy is right here. That iterator is nothing like MBTWC. You really need to understand encodings before proceeding.